# How to store a secret config.php in openshift outside of a git repository?

Tags: php, git, docker, openshift, config

I want to deploy a php app with a dockerfile from a git repository on openshift. The php app includes a config.php file with passwords. I can't put (secret) config.php in the (public) git repository. Where can i store config.php secure? In Openshift secrets service? How can i embed config.php/access passwords?

Comment: use environment vars [getenv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php), it's pretty much the standard

Answer (score 0):

@Lawrence Cherone comment solved my problem by using environment vars getenv().